# How to make Bootstrap card stretch to screen height inside a column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a simple grid layout in React with 2 cards, each in one column. How can I make the card on the left stretch to fill the column (as tall as screen) and when content expands inside, get a scrollbar for it while keeping the second one intact (and still align to the middle of the screen)?

```js
<header className="App-header">
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col md={4}>
        <Card>with text here</Card>
      </Col>
      <Col md={8} className="align-self-center">
        <Card>with other text here</Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
</header>
```

and the css:

```css
.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 59px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 59px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
}
```

this is how the UI looks right now:
[image: current UI]

Also codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-lumiere-jv0wv?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Container`, `Row`, `Col md={4}` and the `Card` - add the `className="h-100"` which will increase the `Col`’s and `Card`’s height to `100vh - 59px`

Then you can add the `overflow-y: auto` or add the `className` (in bootstrap style) `overflow-auto` on the `Card`

To center the right `Card` add `className = "align-items-center"` on the `Row`

Eg:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Card, Col, Container, Row, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Container className="h-100">
          <Row className="h-100 align-items-center"> /* <-- put the align items here */
            <Col md={4} className="treeViewComponent h-100">
              <Card className="h-100 overflow-auto">
                <Card.Body>Text here</Card.Body>
                <Card.Footer>
                  <Button>Do stuff</Button>
                </Card.Footer>
              </Card>
            </Col>
            <Col md={8} className="compressionComponent align-items-center">
              <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                  More text here text here text here text here text here text
                  here text here text here text here text here{" "}
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
```

and the style for the `App-header`

```css
.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  height: calc(100vh - 59px);
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't change anything. Check the sandbox link I added as well.

Comment: In your sand box you have not modified anything. Plus, I am on mobile so I can’t quite get the actual view you intented.

Comment: you need to add `h-100` for both `Col` and `Card` plus - an extra `overflow-auto` for `Card`

Comment: The first time I changed the code to what you said before the edit, it didn't work. Now I applied your changes to sandbox and it still didn't work.

Comment: Hm... That is strange. I was sure it would work.

Comment: Just to test, I just copy-pasted your code over mine in the sandbox, and no changes happened.

Comment: @TermoZour I have found the solution. The issue is with the `App-Header`. Its display is set to flex which is interfering with the heights of its children. I have updated the sandbox. see

Comment: Actually the only thing that was missing was to just remove `min-height`, `max-height` and set `height` of `App-Header` to `calc(100vh - 59px)`. The rest of the properties have been left the same. Why did that work?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. But I thinks its because of the `display:flex` property (or maybe not). You actually does’nt require the advantages of `flex` in `AppHeader` because the `Header` tag itself suffice your requirements and the `Row` itself is a `flex`;

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should simply be able to add `height: 100%` to css of the column you wish to expand, and it should fill the container.

To enable scrolling only when needed, set the css property `overflow: auto` to the scrollable container.

Your css looks like the other card should stay in the middle, regardless of these changes.

Comment: I added `h-100` to the column I want to stretch and nothing happens. Checking with Inspect Element, it goes as tall as the row. If I stretch the row as well, then the right card is not centered anymore.

Comment: If the row is a flex row, you can forget the `height` properties on the Cols and simply use `align-self: stretch;` on the col you wish to expand, and `align-self: center;` on the col you wish to center. (Keep the row with (height: 100%, though)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Bootstrap classes, then add the class `vh-100` to the left card. And in custom CSS add `overflow-y : auto` for scrolling only when required.

Comment: This didn't work. The card indeed became longer, but it became the same height as my browser window, therefore overflowing my divs and overwriting any padding I would have added to the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using flex. Perhaps you could use the `align-items: stretch;` definition and assign a `max-height` to your parent container.

- `align-items: stretch;` makes the child items occupy all available height.
- If you limit the parent container's height than you could apply the overflow to an inner element.

Comment: You'd probably have to change your structure a little bit, but it could work with that combination.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-hidden`,`vh-100` and `mh-100` to the left column...

```
       <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <Container className="">
              <Row className="align-items-center overflow-hidden">
                <Col
                  md={4}
                  className="treeViewComponent vh-100 mh-100 overflow-hidden"
                >
                  <Card className="h-100 overflow-auto">
                    <Card.Body>Text here</Card.Body>
                    <Card.Footer>
                      <Button>Do stuff</Button>
                    </Card.Footer>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md={8} className="compressionComponent align-items-center">
                  <Card>
                    <Card.Body>
                      More text here text here text here text here text here text
                      here text here text here text here text here{" "}
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
          </header>
       </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/vbMAhSXkLe